# Replace a string in MySQL column using insert or update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to replace a string like "`example.com`" with "`newdomain.com`" in a MySQL table called "`wp_options`" with a column name "`option_value`".

I have seen a lot of other questions about replacement but the problem is that they are all using the `REPLACE` function, which damages the structure of my table because it removes the row (if matches) and inserts a new one([1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)), which makes the primary key and unique id disappears (for example, this is causing me to lose my theme configuration).

Is there a way to replace such string using the `INSERT` function? or the `UPDATE`?

Comment: Those solutions do not use the `REPLACE()` *function*.  They are using the `REPLACE` statement.  The two are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `update` statement should do it:

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET    option_value = 'newdomain.com'
WHERE  option_value = 'example.com'
```

**EDIT:**

If the requirement is to search within the value as clarified by the comment below, you can use the [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET    option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'example.com', 'newdomain.com')
WHERE  option_value LIKE '%example.com%'
```

Comment: But this doesn't search for the string in all the column, it just replaces it if it equals example.com, what I am asking for is to search and replace as a string (I mean, even if i have something like example.com/posts/something, it should replace it here too).

Comment: @Madno I misunderstood the question then. See my edited answer for a solution that should accommodate this requirement.